# RSS Feed App BlankPage/Crash

Tags: java, android, rss

I wanted to create an RSS Reader for Android to display news (specifically financial news) from a website, so was looking at various tutorials on how to go about this.

I found a good tutorial, the project is hosted on GitHub @ https://github.com/nerdability/AndroidRssReader

I imported the project to Android Studio, corrected the dependancies. Ran the program, just to a get a blank screen on the app.

The URL specified in the **ArticleListFragment.java** was -

```
private static final String BLOG_URL = "http://blog.nerdability.com/feeds/posts/default";
```

Then I found it that this website is down, hence the blank page. I replaced the link with a different feed, say -

```
private static final String BLOG_URL = "http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-and-rss.html#comments";
```

And ran the program

The app crashed on startup. Checked logcat for this -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.nerdability.android.rss.RssService$1.run(RssService.java:52)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5293)
        at com.nerdability.android.rss.RssService.onPostExecute(RssService.java:49)
        at com.nerdability.android.rss.RssService.onPostExecute(RssService.java:27)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The project uses AsyncTask for the Network call as well - Can be seen in **RssService.java**
Any clue why this is happening? Refer to GitHub link for code reference.

Comment: I'm guessing your're not getting a valid rss response since your link there doesn't point to a rss feed. According to this https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933?hl=en your blogger feed url should be in this format  http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

Comment: @freddieptf I changed the URL to 

private static final String BLOG_URL = "http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default";

Still crashes on start-up. I get the "loading" progress bar, then it crashes. Is it that the app is unable to handle all this data? OR some other issue? 

Logcat - Still get 
`22353-22353/com.nerdability.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nerdability.android, PID: 22353`
Followed by errors provided in the main post.

Comment: Open your RssService and in the onPostExecute check if the List returned by doInBackground actually has something in it or it's just null